# Python: how to select contiguity neighbors of matrix values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix like the following:

```
A = array([[12,  6, 14,  8,  4,  1],
       [18, 13,  8, 10,  9, 19],
       [ 8, 15,  6,  5,  6, 18],
       [ 3,  0,  2, 14, 13, 12],
       [ 4,  4,  5, 19,  0, 14],
       [16,  8,  7,  7, 11,  0],
       [ 3, 11,  2, 19, 11,  5],
       [ 4,  2,  1,  9, 12, 12]])
```

For each cell I want to select the values in a `radius` of `k=2` closest cells.

For instance if I select the `A[3,4]` I would like a submatrix like the following

```
array([[18, 13,  8, 10,  9],
       [ 8, 15,  6,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  0,  2, 14, 13],
       [ 4,  4,  5, 19,  0],
       [16,  8,  7,  7, 11]])
```

I defined the following function

```
def queen_neighbourhood(Adj, in_row, in_col, k):
    j=k
    k+=1
    neighbourhood = Adj[in_row-j:in_row+k, in_col-j:in_col+k]
    return neighbourhood
```

such as `queen_neighbourhood(A, 3, 2, 2)` returns

```
array([[18, 13,  8, 10,  9],
       [ 8, 15,  6,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  0,  2, 14, 13],
       [ 4,  4,  5, 19,  0],
       [16,  8,  7,  7, 11]])
```

However it does not work in borders.

For instance, for the cell `[0,0]` I would like to have

```
array([[12, 6,  14],
       [18, 13,  8],
       [ 8, 15, 16])
```

but it returns `queen_neighbourhood(A, 0, 0, 2)`

```
array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid negative indices:

```
    neighbourhood = Adj[max(in_row-j, 0) : in_row+k,
                        max(in_col-j, 0) : in_col+k]
```

Comment: it does not work on the bottom corner `queen_neighbourhood(A, 9, 9, 2)` returns `array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=int64)` while it should return `array([[2, 14, 13], [5, 19, 0, [ 7, 7,  11]])`

Comment: nope you' re A.shape is(8,6) , why you want it to work on 9*9 array, check my answer an tel me if it works

Comment: @emax My result is correct. I have no idea why you expect `array([[2, 14, 13], [5, 19, 0, [ 7, 7,  11]])`. That's not even valid syntax (missing a `]`), has radius 1 instead of 2, and isn't at `9, 9` but at `4, 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer; taking into consideration the extreme values

```
def queen_neighbourhood(Adj, in_row, in_col, k):
j=k
k+=1
neighbourhood = Adj[max(in_row-j, 0) : min(in_row+k,Adj.shape[0]),
                    max(in_col-j, 0) : min(in_col+k,Adj.shape[1])]
return(neighbourhood)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy roll to ensure you are always dealing with the middle value,

```
import numpy as np

def queen_neighbourhood(Adj, in_row, in_col, k):
    j=k
    k+=1
    midrow = int(Adj.shape[0]/2.)+1
    midcol = int(Adj.shape[1]/2.)+1
    Ashift = np.roll(Adj,(in_row-midrow,in_col-midcol),(0,1))
    neighbourhood = Ashift[1:k+1, 1:k+1]
    return neighbourhood


A = np.array([[18, 13,  8, 10,  9],
       [ 8, 15,  6,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  0,  2, 14, 13],
       [ 4,  4,  5, 19,  0],
       [16,  8,  7,  7, 11]])

print(A)
An = queen_neighbourhood(A, 0, 0, 2)
print(An)
```

which gives,

```
[[11 16  8]
 [ 9 18 13]
 [ 6  8 15]]
```

Comment: the problem is that If I run `An = queen_neighbourhood1(A, 3, 2, 2)` returns only the adjacent values `An = array([[14, 13, 12], [19,  0, 14], [ 7, 11,  0]])` while I want `An = array([[18, 13,  8, 10,  9],[ 8, 15,  6,  5,  6], [ 3,  0,  2, 14, 13],[ 4,  4,  5, 19,  0], [16,  8,  7,  7, 11]])`

Comment: I think the indexing might be off...